# Почему у массива вдруг не оказалось метода each()

Tags: ооп, массивы, javascript

```
$(".test").live("click", function () {
    var prodList = new ProductList(".item");
    //console.log(prodList);
    prodList.getProductById(1);
});

function Product(productSelector) {
    var params = productSelector.find(".params .params_solution");
    var tmp = this;
    params.each(function () {
        tmp[$(this).find("input[name=paramName]").val()] = $(this).find("input[name=paramValue]").val();
    });
}

function ProductList(productsSelector) {
    var products = $(productsSelector);
    //все товары
    this.product = new Array();
    var tmp = this.product;
    //добавляем все товары
    products.each(function () {
        var productElement = new Product($(this));
        tmp.push(productElement);
    });

    this.getProductById = function (id) {
        this.product.each(function () {
            console.log(this);
        });
    };
}
```

Проблема в том что:

> `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object],[object Object] has no method 'each'`

в строчке `this.product.each(function(){`. Собственно не могу понять, почему у массива вдруг не оказалось метода each()?

Comment: jQuery головного мозга...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`each` как метод присутствует только у элементов, разве нет?
К массивам применяется

```
 jQuery.each(product, function() {
```

Comment: верно. молодец. +1 )

У массивов есть метод [].forEach(function(element){});

Comment: Спасибо,не обновлял топик и не видел вашего ответа, но все равно спасибо)

Comment: > each как метод присутствует только у элементов, разве нет?

нет

    $([1,2,3]).each(function() {
      console.log('-> ' + this)
    });

Comment: Классический пример того, что сначала стоит изучить javascript, а потом уже переходить к его библиотекам. @CrazyTimon, в чистом js вообще нет встроенных средств для перебора массивов. Метод .forEach() появился в 5 версии ecmascript и не поддерживается старыми версиями браузеров. Массивы до сих пор перебирают циклом.

Answer (score 1):

Уже решил. Проблема была в моей невнимательности. each - это метод JQery, поэтому следует вызывать `$.each(params, function(){});`